# Pygame, how do you fix a part of the screen being black when i make a game?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

A part (specifically the top middle) of the screen is black, once i have added a background, but i can see the rest of the background.

I have tried running it a few times and i have tried searching what might have caused it, i don't have a game loop yet, because nothing is supposed to happen, that might be the problem... sorry the code is long...

```
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
SCREEN_TITLE = "road cross game thing"

WHITE_COLOR = (255,255,255)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 75)

title = SCREEN_TITLE
width = SCREEN_WIDTH
height = SCREEN_HEIGHT

class Game:
    TICK_RATE = 60

    title = SCREEN_TITLE
    width = SCREEN_WIDTH
    height = SCREEN_HEIGHT

    image = pygame.image.load("photo.jpg")
    game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    game_screen.fill(WHITE_COLOR)
    game_screen.fill(WHITE_COLOR)
    game_screen.blit(image, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.set_caption(title)

    is_game_over = False
    did_win = False
    direction = 0

    while not is_game_over:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                is_game_over = True

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pos= pygame.mouse.get_pos()



            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    direction = 0

            print(event)

    game_screen.fill(WHITE_COLOR)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(TICK_RATE)

    object_image1 = pygame.image.load("photo.jpg")
    image1 = pygame.transform.scale(object_image1, (50, 50))

    x_pos = 50
    y_pos = 50

    game_screen.blit(image1,(x_pos, y_pos))

pygame.init()

Game()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

i expected the code to make the whole background my picture.

Comment: Please give an organised explanation of expected output and what you are seeing currently

Comment: you have wrong indentations. After last blit you forgot `pygame.display.update()
`. Your class looks like function but classes are build in different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly there, it's just a bit un-organised.

The reason the screen updating is not what you expect is because the code is drawing and then updating in out-of-order.  In a nutshell, it should make all the drawing operations first, then `update()` them all to the display.  Obviously if you draw and image, then call `fill()`, the first draw operation is not going to be visible, since it's been over-painted.

The `image1` does not fill the entire display because it's only stretched to `( 50, 50 )` whereas the screen is `1500` x `800`.

While I was debugging the code, I moved the initialisation functions into a member function `Game.__init__()`, and the main game loop into a `Game.run()` function.

The OP's indentation is a little messed-up, I expect this is caused by the paste into SO (otherwise the program would not produce the described result).  But it looks like you're loading images inside the main game loop.  It's best to load resources like images, sounds, etc. only once before the user-event loop begins.

```
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
TICK_RATE     = 60
SCREEN_TITLE  = "road cross game thing"

WHITE_COLOR = (255,255,255)


# Initialise PyGame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption( SCREEN_TITLE )
game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT ) )
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 75)


class Game:

    def __init__( self, game_screen ):

        self.game_screen = game_screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load( "photo.jpg" )
        self.object_image1 = pygame.image.load( "photo.jpg" )
        #self.image1 = pygame.transform.scale( self.object_image1, (50, 50) )
        # Scale to fill window
        self.image1 = pygame.transform.scale( self.object_image1, ( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )



    def run( self ):

        is_game_over = False
        did_win      = False
        direction    = 0

        while not is_game_over:

            # Handle user input events
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    is_game_over = True

                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    pos= pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        direction = 0

                print(event)

            # Update the screen
            #game_screen.fill( WHITE_COLOR )
            #game_screen.blit( self.image, (0, 0) )
            #x_pos = 50
            #y_pos = 50
            #game_screen.blit( self.image1, (x_pos, y_pos) )

            # Fill the window with image1
            game_screen.blit( self.image1, ( 0, 0 ) )

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick( TICK_RATE )



# Run the Game
game = Game( game_screen )
game.run()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Glad I could help!